# Jenks Natural Breaks in Python: How to find the optimum number of breaks?

Tags: python, clustering, optimization

I found [this Python implementation](https://github.com/perrygeo/jenks) of the [Jenks Natural Breaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization) algorithm and I could make it run on my Windows 7 machine. It is pretty fast and it finds the breaks in few time, considering the size of my geodata. Before using this clustering algorithm for my data, I was using `sklearn.clustering.KMeans` [(here)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) algorithm. The problem I had with KMeans, was finding the optimum K value parameter, but I "solved" it launching the algorithm for different K values and using `sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score` [(here)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) to find the best K.

My question is: if I tell the Natural Breaks algorithm to find 5 classes (that would be the K), how can I be sure that this is the number of classes that best match my data? How to validate that I am choosing the best number of breaks?

Thanks!

Comment: So that we can objectively determine what "best" means, could you explain the sense in which the classes "match" data?  (Or, really, how you would quantify any degree of mis-matching.)

Comment: Using Silhouette with Jenks should be comparable to using it with kmeans. It's a heuristic and you shouldn't trust it blindly. IMHO the best is to *visualize* your rrsults.

Comment: Whuber: Best, using Silhouette, would mean the number of classes that make the index be closer to 1, according to the definition on sklearn site: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html#sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score

Anony-Mousse: I cannot visualize 20+ variables, prepare maps for that and expect my brain not to mess up with the number of classes. I need to rely on an index that says, "for variable X, the best you can do is to use Y classes". Moreover I need to re-run the analysis several times, the viz approach is slow unfortunately...

Comment: from jenks import jenks: gives following error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name jenks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Jenks Natural Breaks works by optimizing the Goodness of Variance Fit, a value from 0 to 1 where 0 = No Fit and 1 = Perfect Fit.  The key in selecting the number of classes is to find a balance between detecting differences and overfitting your data.  To determine the optimum number of classes, I suggest you use a threshold GVF value you desire and use the number of classes that satisfies this value first.

Below is a function to calculate the Goodness of Variance Fit given an array of values to classify and the number of classes selected:

```
from jenks import jenks
import numpy as np
def goodness_of_variance_fit(array, classes):
    # get the break points
    classes = jenks(array, classes)

    # do the actual classification
    classified = np.array([classify(i, classes) for i in array])

    # max value of zones
    maxz = max(classified)

    # nested list of zone indices
    zone_indices = [[idx for idx, val in enumerate(classified) if zone + 1 == val] for zone in range(maxz)]

    # sum of squared deviations from array mean
    sdam = np.sum((array - array.mean()) ** 2)

    # sorted polygon stats
    array_sort = [np.array([array[index] for index in zone]) for zone in zone_indices]

    # sum of squared deviations of class means
    sdcm = sum([np.sum((classified - classified.mean()) ** 2) for classified in array_sort])

    # goodness of variance fit
    gvf = (sdam - sdcm) / sdam

    return gvf

def classify(value, breaks):
    for i in range(1, len(breaks)):
        if value < breaks[i]:
            return i
    return len(breaks) - 1
```

For example, consider you decide the GVF should be at least .8, then you could increment the number of classes until the GVF is satisfied:

```
gvf = 0.0
nclasses = 2
while gvf < .8:
    gvf = goodness_of_variance_fit(array, nclasses)
    nclasses += 1
```

Comment: Hi, useful post. Can I know how to interpret Gvf = 87% for n_classes = 4? Does it mean with 4 classes, we are able to seperate the data (into bins) correctly by 87%?